# R read.table vs read.csv

Tags: r, csv

```
grades <- read.table("studentgrades.csv",header = TRUE,row.names="StudentID", sep = ",")

gradess <- read.csv("studentgrades.csv",header = TRUE,row.names="StudentID", sep = ",")
```

The result of `read.table` is:

```
grades
[1] First          Last           Math           Science        Social.Studies
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

The result of `read.csv` is:

```
gradess
   First       Last Math Science Social.Studies
11   Bob      Smith   90      80             67
12  Jane      Weary   75      NA             80
10   Dan "Thornton"   65      75             70
40  Mary    O'Leary   90      95             92
```

I just don't know why the `read.tables` can not give me the right result.

Comment: Can you include the first 3 lines of your input file `studentgrades.csv` ?

Comment: Can you just show the output using `readLines` i.e. `lines <- head(readLines("studentgrades.csv"))`

Comment: I agree that seeing at least a few lines of the input would really help narrow down what's happening here.

Comment: GIven the presence of the single quote in the `Last` column of your data, I suspect the problem comes from the different defaults that `read.csv` and `read.table` have for the argument `quote`. `read.csv` only uses the double quotes as the default whereas `read.table` uses both single and double quotes. For example: `txt <- "a, b, c
1, 2, this
3, 4, thing's"; read.csv(text = txt);` compared to `read.table(text = txt, sep = ",", header = T)` reproduces your case

Comment: Thanks Chrisss, you are right, I tried your example and now I know why, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the quote `(')` in `O'Leary` of last name column. You will need to change the default `quote` option in `read.table` which is set to the `(')` by default to get desired result.

If you use `quote=NULL` in `read.table` like below

```
grades <- read.table("studentgrades.csv",header = TRUE,sep=",",quote=NULL,row.names="StudentID")
```

Then you get the desired result.

```
> grades
    First        Last Math  Science Social.Studies
11    Bob       Smith   90       80             67
12   Jane       Weary   75       NA             80
10    Dan  "Thornton"   65       75             70
40   Mary     O'Leary   90       95             92
```

Comment: thanks so much and really appreciate. the book did not include quote = NULL but give the right results so I was wondering why. Your answer help me get through it. Thanks